# c++ reference to array

Tags: c++, char, pass-by-reference

I can't create a reference to an `unsigned char` array `z` within `myfunc()`. I've tried several ways but just can't figure it out. This is my most recent attempt:

```
int myfunc (int &y, unsigned char (&z)[2]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
 int y = 1;
 unsigned char z[2];

 int x = myfunc(y, z[2]);
}

int myfunc(int &y, unsigned char (&z)[2]) {
 y = 123;
 z[0] = foo;
 z[1] = bar;
 return 456;
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
error: in passing argument 2 of ‘int myfunc(int&, unsigned char (&)[2])’
```

For line `int myfunc (int &y, unsigned char (&z)[2]);`

And:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘unsigned char (&)[2]’ from expression of type ‘unsigned char’
```

For line `int x = myfunc(y, x);`

How should I be referencing the array it self (and not an array of references?) ?

Comment: Using a vector makes this really easy, and is much better than raw arrays otherwise. Anyways, you're calling your function by passing a single element in. Use `z`, not `z[2]`.

Comment: I am trying to learn vectors along side this, how would that make this easier? The only way I can see to make this work is to make the array globally defined which as I understand it is not good.

Comment: With a vector, your signature would be: `int myfunc (int &y, std::vector<unsigned char> &z)`. They provide syntax you'd expect from using other types of parameters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
myfunc(y, z[2]);
```

The expression `z[2]` is of type `unsigned char` (and refers to an element beyond the end of the array, so it is undefined behavior). You want to do:

```
myfunc(y, z);
```

Comment: Thanks you for the speedy response :)

Answer (score 2):

call should be: `int x = myfunc(y, z);`

This is because `z` represents an `unsigned char [2]` but `z[2]` represents type `char`. Also `z[2]` accesses array out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks to you also for the speedy response :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused about what you're trying to do.  IMHO your signature should just be `int myfunc (int &y, unsigned char z[2])`.

Arrays don't get passed "by value" (if you want to do that, then using a vector is the easiest way), and the default makes your `get_mac` function (which I assume was supposed to be `myfunc`) work as desired (unless I've misunderstood your desire).

The signature `int myfunc (int &y, unsigned char (&z)[2])` *suggests* that you might want to change the value of `z` itself in the caller (not just elements of `z`), but even the caller can't do that (!), and you'll get an error if you try.  If you want that, use an actual pointer.

There *is* a legitimate use for passing the array by reference using the syntax in your example, which is to enforce the declared array size.  But if you're just learning, I don't think you need to worry about this yet.